# Download link in html5

Tags: html, css

I'm trying put on my page download link, where I can download pdf file. I'm using this block below but when I'm trying download file it's failure. How can I fix this problem?

```
<div>
       <a href="http://www.mypage.com/documents" download="name_of_file.pdf" class=" btn btn-lg btn-outline">Download CV english version </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does "it's ending failure" mean specifically?

Comment: I cannot download file

Comment: Well for starters, your link points to a folder, not a PDF file.

Comment: Pdf file is inside folder that's name is "documents". I thought the solve my problem is create path: http://www.mywebsite.com/documents/name_of_file.pdf but it is not working too. I cannot download file when I put my website to server.

Comment: Does the file actually exist at that path? Can you load the file at that path without the download attribute?

Answer (score 0):

`http://www.mypage.com/documents` is a folder, not a file. Try changing the `href` to a file

Example:

```
<div>
   <a href="http://www.mypage.com/documents/your_specific_file.jpg" class=" btn btn-lg btn-outline">Download CV english version </a>
</div>
```

You can change the name of your file with the `download` property. For example if you add `download="New_name.jpg"` the file will be downloaded as `New_name.jpg` and not `your_specific_file.jpg`